# Find an example of weak convergent sequence which is not Cauchy

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Is there a sequence if functions $f_j$ such that $f_j \rightharpoonup 0$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ but $f_j$ is not a Cauchy sequence in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $L^2(\mathbb R)$ is a separable Hilbert space. For example, the weighted Hermite polynomials form a complete orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Prove that, if $H$ is a separable Hilbert space with complete orthonormal basis $\{ e_i \}$, then the sequence $e_1, e_2, e_3, \dots $ weakly converges to $0$, but is not Cauchy.

[Remember, any vector in $x \in H$ can be written in the form $x =\sum_i a_i e_i$, where $a_i = \langle x, e_i \rangle$, and note that $\sum_i |a_i|^2  = || x ||^2 < \infty$ by Parseval's theorem.]

---

Alternatively, consider $f_n = \tfrac 1 {\sqrt{\pi}}\sin( n x) 1_{[0,2\pi]}$. This is an orthonormal sequence in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, though it is not a complete orthonormal basis. Note that for any $x \in L^2 (\mathbb R)$, we have $\sum_n \langle x, f_n \rangle^2 \leq ||x||^2$ by Bessel's inequality. Then use the same idea...